# bash scripting language print a list of numbers using a loop

Tags: linux, bash, loops

I want to print in a text file (numberlist.txt), using bash, all the numbers from 000000 to 999999, one number in each line. Example:

```
000000
000001
000002

...

999999
```

This is my code: (WHEN I RUN IT NOTHING HAPPENS)

```
#!/bin/bash 
CONT=0
MAX_NUM=1000000
FILE_NAME=numberlist.txt

#While counter CONT is lower than MAX_NUM (-lt, “lower #than”) the loop is executed
until [ $CONT -lt $MAX_NUM ]; do
     printf "%000002d\n" $CONT > $FILE_NAME
     #CONT= CONT + 1
     let CONT+=1
done
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: change "until" by "while", "%000002d" by "%06d" and CONT+=1 by CONT++, and > $FILE_NAME by >>$FILE_NAME.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui that seems like a better answer than comment to me

Comment: @EricRenouf: I've not tested it, could be there are more issues. If there are no more issues, anyone can write a answer with "community attribution".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of opening and closing the file a million times, do it just once by redirecting the output of **the loop** instead of the printf:

```
#!/bin/bash 
CONT=0
MAX_NUM=1000000
FILE_NAME=numberlist.txt

while [ $CONT -lt $MAX_NUM ]; do
     printf "%06d\n" $CONT 
     #CONT= CONT + 1
     let CONT++
done > $FILE_NAME
```

Comment: A C-style `for` loop would be simpler and more elegant. `for ((cont=0; cont < 1000000; ++cont)); do`...

Answer (score 0):

Converting the comments from  `pasaba por aqui` as answer.:

```
#!/bin/bash 
CONT=0
MAX_NUM=1000000
FILE_NAME=numberlist.txt

#While counter CONT is lower than MAX_NUM (-lt, “lower #than”) the loop is executed
while [ $CONT -lt $MAX_NUM ]; do
     printf "%06d\n" $CONT >>$FILE_NAME
     #CONT= CONT + 1
     let CONT++
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use bash version 4 at least you can do simply

```
echo -en {000000..999999}'\n' > numberlist.txt
```

No need for loops. The `-en` and the `\n` are to put each number on its own line.